# Converting the following criteria into SQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have the following criteria that I am using,..

```
List<boop> books =null;
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(boop.class);
        ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
        proList.add(Projections.property("AAA"));
        proList.add(Projections.property("BBB"));
        RETURN  criteria.list();
```

please advise how can I convert it in HQL..

Comment: YOU DON'T HAVE TO WRITE IN ALL CAPS JUST BECAUSE YOU ARE USED TO IT IN SQL!

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040684/conversion-of-below-criteria-into-hql

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Projections javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html). Each `Projections` property corresponds to a database field.

```
select b.AAA, b.BBB
from boop b
```