# Conversion of below criteria into HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I have the following criteria  please advise how can I convert the below criteria into HQL , as I want to use HQL

```
public List<tttBook> findtooks() {

            List<tttBook> tooks =null;
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(tttBook.class);
            ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
            proList.add(Projections.property("Id"));
            proList.add(Projections.property("longName"));
            tooks = criteria.list();
            return tooks;

        }
```

also please let me know in this above criteria what is wrong since right now it is fetching all the attributes of the object and it takes lots of time i think there is something wrong with my projections implementation.

Comment: your hql is "from tttBook"

Comment: @Angga but i want to fetch certain selected columns as table contains many coulmns which I don't want please advise

Comment: so you want to return it as incomplete List<tttBook> with only id and longName on it? you maybe consider using List<map> instead. If yes i will give you the example(tttBook/map).

Comment: @Yeah Thanks please advise for that example or update the post,Thanks in advance with only id and longname

Comment: @Angga please post the code for how to return only id and long name from hql and that is also of type list<tttBook> , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another constructor in your object `tttBook`. Also you should follow naming convention and call class starting with capital letter and properties with small letter.

```
package yourpath;

public class TttBook {
   private Long id;
   private String longName;

   public TttBook(Long id, String longName) {
      this.id = id;
      this.longName = longName;
   }

   // getters, setters
}
```

**Query**

```
List<TttBook > list = (List<TttBook >) session.createQuery("select 
   new yourpath.TttBook(id, longName) from TttBook").list();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
public List<tttBook> findtooks() {
    Session s = HiberUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<tttBook> tooks =new ArrayList<tttBook>;
    List result = session.createQuery("select a.Id, a.longName from tttBook t").List();
    for(int i =0; i< result.size();i++){
        Object[] objects = result.get(i);
        tttBook t = new tttBook();
        t.setId(objects[0]);
        t.setLongName(objects[1]);
    tooks.add(t);
    }

    return tooks;

}
```

Comment: so in this way you are taking the records from hibernate in form of object [] and then casting them and setting itin pojo .

Comment: so you want to cast it automatically? i don't know what you exactly want, that's why i ask. if you looking to HQL that return object that already parsed, you will need @SqlResultSetMapping.

Comment: yeah now you got the point ,rite now  tooks = criteria.list(); is returning me object array(Object[]), I was looking to cast it automatically to class tttBook type and nt object[] could you please advise more about @sqlResultSetMapping for this.

Comment: please update your eample with this annotation that will help to grasp

Comment: if you use HQL then return will always be object[](if use select some field) or entities, if you use @sqlResultSetMapping anotation you will not use HQL, but native queries(SQL), is that ok for you?

Comment: I have another suggestion for you if you don,t want to use SQL. You will need to create new entity that a copy of tttBook but delete all other variable(and getters setters) that you don't need. then use that in your hql queries "from halfTttBook".